# Error message when using a compiled function in NSum

Tags: numerics, compile

Below is a simple example to illustrate the problem

```
test = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, n]
```

Now, `Table` works fine

```
Table[test[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

But `NSum`

```
NSum[test[n], {n, 1, 10}]
```

gives errors as

> CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument n at position 1 should be a machine-size integer. >>

What does it mean?

---

**Update**

Simon Woods suggested that we could simply ignore this warning. But I don't think so. See the timing below.

```
In[2]:= NSum[test[n], {n, 1, 100000}] // AbsoluteTiming


During evaluation of In[2]:= CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument n at position 1 should be a machine-size integer. >>

During evaluation of In[2]:= CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument n at position 1 should be a machine-size integer. >>

Out[2]= {0.270994, 5.00005*10^9}

In[4]:= Sum[test[n], {n, 1, 100000}] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[4]= {0.114388, 5000050000}
```

`NSum` is significantly slower than `Sum`

Comment: While it's a different warning the cause is the same as in the duplicate question - symbolic evaluation of the summand. You can ignore the warning, but if it bothers you use `NSum[Hold@test[n],{n,1,10}]` or create a wrapper function for `test` which only lets through the correct type of argument e.g. `test2[n_Integer]:=test[n]`

Comment: I don't reproduce your results on the timing - I get a much smaller time from `Quiet@NSum[test[n], {n, 1, 100000}] // RepeatedTiming` than I do from `Quiet@Sum[test[n], {n, 1, 100000}] // RepeatedTiming`

Comment: I get the same as Jason - `NSum` is about 20 times faster than `Sum`

Comment: @SimonWoods I found my timing is somewhat wrong. I updated my post. But still `NSum` is slower. I think `RepeatedTiming` is lying, maybe it is using caching? Using `AbsoluteTiming` `Nsum` is slower on my computer

Comment: Processing and issuing the warning message has a cost, of course. With `Quiet` as shown by Jason the message is suppressed and `NSum` is much faster. When I said you could ignore the warning, I meant that the result would be correct. If it's important to save that fraction of a second then don't ignore it.

Comment: @SimonWoods Thank you so much for explanation.  For speed, `Quiet` ignore the message and is already much faster, so what do you mean by "don't ignore it" in the last sentence? And I found this warning message is common if we use compiled function in `Integrate` and `NIntegrate`. Your comment is much clearer than the answer in that duplicate question.